# Drop double-quotes found in data in a Presto SQL-compartible database (AWS Athena)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, presto, amazon-athena

In a Presto-compatible database (AWS Athena) I have some rows that contain values in double-quotes, mixed with values without double-quotes

e.g. column "postal code" can have `"00100"` and `00100`.

What SQL query can I issue to remove all double-quotes found, so `"00100"` becomes `00100`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
replace(postal_code, '"', '')
```

This can be in an `update` or `select`.

Note:  This removes *all* double quotes.  If you have some values that could have double quotes in them, then you need more complicated expressions.  In my experience, though, a column named `postal_code` would never have double quotes so this is safe.